# Why can Flux.fromIterable(Iterable) call Iterable.iterator() twice?

Tags: java, iterator, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spliterator

The [`Flux.fromIterable(Iterable)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#fromIterable-java.lang.Iterable-) has an interesting sentence in its contract:

> The `Iterable.iterator()` method will be **invoked** at least once and **at most twice** for each subscriber.

What is the scenario when the method needs to call the `Iterable.iterator()` twice?

There **is** an explanation for it in the documentation, however I don't fully understand it:

> This operator inspects the `Iterable`'s `Spliterator` to assess if the iteration can be guaranteed to be finite. Since the default `Spliterator` wraps the `Iterator` we can have two `Iterable.iterator()` calls. This second invocation is skipped on a `Collection` however, a type which is assumed to be always finite.

Answer (score 1):

Until [that](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/3295) issue was recently resolved, `Iterable.iterator()` was actually called twice. [Here](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/v3.4.25/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/FluxIterable.java) is `FluxIterable` source code of   reactor-core 3.4.25:

```
@Override
public void subscribe(CoreSubscriber<? super T> actual) {
    // ...
    try {
        knownToBeFinite = FluxIterable.checkFinite(iterable);
        it = iterable.iterator();
    }
    // ...
}
```

while `FluxIterable.checkFinite(iterable)` is

```
static <T> boolean checkFinite(Iterable<T> iterable) {
    return iterable instanceof Collection || iterable.spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SIZED);
}
```

and `Iterable.spliterator` is

```
default Spliterator<T> spliterator() {
    return Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator(), 0);
}
```

So the first call to `.iterator` is made to obtain an `Spliterator` and examine whether it's finite, and the second call is performed in order to actually obtain iterator that would be used to iterate over the elements.

Since mentioned issue has been resolved, I'm not sure whether that notice about two `iterator()` calls is still valid. May be calling `iterator()` only once now is a kind of undocumented feature that is not reliable in feature.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, now I do understand. However, **if** they fixed it in reactor, it is indeed unclear why they left the "called twice" text in the method contract. Maybe just forgotten? Because knowing for sure that the iterator can be called only once **is** a big advantage - in some very special cases you even have iterators which cannot be called multiple times.